# How to choose which model to fit to data?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

My question is given a particular dataset and a binary classification task, is there a way we can choose a particular type of model that is likely to work best? e.g. consider the titanic dataset on kaggle here: https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic. Just by analyzing graphs and plots, are there any general rules of thumb to pick Random Forest vs KNNs vs Neural Nets or do I just need to test them out and then pick the best performing one?

Note: I'm not talking about image data since CNNs are obv best for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to test different models to see how they perform.
The top algorithms based on the papers and kaggle seem to be boosting algorithms, XGBoost, LightGBM, AdaBoost, stack of all of those together, or just Random Forests in general. But there are instances where Logistic Regression can outperform them.
So just try them all. If the dataset is >100k, you're not gonna lose that much time, and you might learn something valuable about your data.